# Devexpress, how to add Button to SummaryItem

Tags: c#, button, gridview, devexpress, table-footer

I have grid with SummaryItem. It is possible to add button there instead of text? I know I can add button to column (gridView1.Columns["col_name"].ShowButtonMode = ShowButtonModeEnum.ShowAlways). If it's not possible, maybe adding some image with event OnClick?
Alternative is to add SimpleButton and set anchor or something but I'd like to try above first (if possible of course).

Comment: In winform, you have to do some CustomDraw to have a button in the footer.

Comment: You should be able to modify this example to draw a button to the footer rather than the header:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E2793